# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Escritorio/pdf_tabla_Clientes.pdf (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, swing, file-io, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

I can't put the path of  my desktop in my mac to save the pdf.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Escritorio/pdf_tabla_Clientes.pdf (No
>   such file or directory)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:194)
>     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:84)    at
>   GenerarPDFEmpleados.(GenerarPDFEmpleados.java:58)   at
>   Reportes$1.actionPerformed(Reportes.java:61)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122) e

Heres my code:

```
public class GenerarPDFEmpleados
{
    private String strNombreDelPDF;

    private  Font fuenteNegra10 = new Font();
    private  Font fuente8 = new Font();
    private  Font fuenteAzul25 = new Font();

    Color grisClaro = new Color( 230,230,230);  
    Color azulClaro = new Color( 124,195,255 );

    //############# VARIABLES PARA MANEJO DE BASE DE DATOS ########################
    //Guarda la consulta operacion a realizar
    String strConsultaSQL;
    //Apuntador a la conexion
    Connection conn = null; 
    //Para ejecutar operaciones SQL
    Statement estSQL1;
    //Para guardar los resultados de una operacion SELECT
    ResultSet rs;
    Document document;
    PdfWriter writer;
    String strRotuloPDF;

    //Metodo principal del ejemplo
    public GenerarPDFEmpleados(String titulo, String nomPDF)
    {
        strRotuloPDF = titulo;
        strNombreDelPDF = nomPDF;
        try
        {       //Hoja tamanio carta, rotarla (cambiar a horizontal)
            document = new Document( PageSize.LETTER.rotate() );

            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(
            // that listens to the document
                    document,
                    // direccionar el PDF-stream a un archivo
                    new FileOutputStream("/Escritorio/"+strNombreDelPDF));
            document.open();

            agregarMetaDatos(document);
            agregarContenido(document);

            document.close();

            System.out.println("Se ha generado el PDF: "+ strNombreDelPDF);

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there really a directory `/Escritorio/` or is is something like `/home/Escritorio/`?  Or is it supposed to be `/home/username/Escritorio/`?

Comment: `/Escritorio/` is looking for a directory at the root of the current volume context...presumably this does not exist.  Is the file stored on the file system or within the application context as an embedded resource?

Comment: Escritorio its my desktop folder of my mac any ideas?